how do I append the output of a dask_cudf apply function to the original dask_cudf?
I am applying a function (e.g. letter frequency) to a dask_cudf dataframe that consists of a single column of words of fixed length.
I am trying to merge the output or append the output into the original dataframe, but I've been wracking my brains around finding a way to do this without having to compute(). The output is generated very quickly, but because I need to do some kind of conversion, the time increase by 1000x.
I'm using RAPIDS 24.10 on a Linux Mint box equipped with a 3060 GeForce GPU.
import itertools
import re
import os, sys
import tempfile
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import collections
import numpy.ma as ma

from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

import tracemalloc

import threading
import tqdm
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing as mp

import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da
import dask.bag as db
import dask.delayed as dl

import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

import cupy, cudf
import cudf.pandas
cudf.pandas.install()

import dask
dask.config.set({"array.backend": "cupy"})
dask.config.set({"dataframe.backend": "cudf"})

import dask_cudf



def freq(row):
    return len(set(row[0]))/len(row[0])

words = ['password','username','database','function','variable','algorithm','protocol','callback','unittest','pipeline']

a = dask_cudf.from_cudf(cudf.DataFrame(data=words, columns=['words']).to_pandas(nullable=True))
#a.compute()

b = a.apply(freq, axis=1, meta=pd.DataFrame({'selfhyb': [0]}))
#b.compute()

The expectation is that I can find a way to merge a and b into one, or to simply assign a new column to a with the output from b. but I haven't had any success without having to compute() which becomes super slow and pointless.
My confusion lies in the format of b, which shows up as:
<class 'dask_expr._collection.DataFrame'>

This seems neither to be a cudf.Series, nor a bonafide cudf.Dataframe so I'm not sure how to coerce this without having to compute(). Both are "indexed", and I think they should be able to be linked to allow downstream filtering etc. etc. etc.

This is the only thing that has worked:
result = dask_cudf.concat([a, b], axis=1)


This example is mixing the use of cudf.pandas, cudf, dask_cudf, and dask.dataframe APIs in a way this is sure to cause problems and confusion. I'm pretty sure you are just ending up with a mix of CPU- and GPU-backed data.
The biggest problem is that you are using cudf.pandas with Dask, and this isn't supported (yet). This is because dask.dataframe already offers some CPU/GPU portability, and the monkey-patching used in cudf.pandas breaks some the underlying dispatching mechanisms in Dask.
If I understand correctly, your goal is to assign a new "selfhyb" column to a DataFrame with a "words" column. This can be done with concat, but a simple column assignment is probably more natural.
If you are working with a large amount of data, and need to use dask.dataframe in lieu of cudf.pandas (or cudf directly), then you should simply set the "dataframe.backend" config to "cudf", and use dask.dataframe directly. Do not import cudf.pandas or dask_cudf (you can import dask_cudf, but it will already be used automatically by dask.dataframe).
The dask.dataframe-version of your code would probably look something like this:
import pandas as pd
import cudf

import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask
dask.config.set({'dataframe.backend': 'cudf'})

words = ['password','username','database','function','variable','algorithm','protocol','callback','unittest','pipeline']
df = dd.from_pandas(cudf.DataFrame({'words': words}), npartitions=1)

def freq(row):
    return len(set(row))/len(row)

# NOTE: Unlike cudf.pandas, dask.dataframe will NOT automatically
# fall back from cudf->pandas when something isn't supported by
# the cudf backend (e.g. most `apply` operations)
df['selfhyb'] = df['words'].to_backend("pandas").apply(freq, meta=pd.Series([0])).to_backend("cudf")
df.compute()

Note that cudf has limited support for apply. So, when you are using pandas (via cudf.pandas), this apply operation will not actually happen on the GPU. When you use dask.dataframe, it is your responsibility to "move" the backend back to "pandas" before the apply call.
If you want to avoid falling back to the CPU, you will probably need to use cudf's string-accessor functionality. I don't think there is a simple way to get the number of unique characters in each series element, but this can currently be done with a non-public function:
...
df = dd.from_pandas(cudf.DataFrame({'words': words}), npartitions=1)

def cudf_freq(ser):
    unique = cudf.Series._from_column(ser.str._split_by_character()).list.unique().list.len()
    return unique / ser.str.len()

df['selfhyb'] = df['words'].map_partitions(cudf_freq, meta=cudf.Series([0]))
df.compute()

Other Notes

If you are not working with large amounts of data, and it fits comfortably in the memory of a single GPU, then you can avoid using Dask altogether.

If you are working with large amounts of data, please checkout the Dask cuDF best-practices documentation.

The 'dask_expr._collection.DataFrame' type you are observing is just a "pandas"-backed dask.dataframe object. Starting with dask-2024.3.0, Dask replaced its legacy DataFrame API with the dask-expressions library related github issue.



Thanks for that answer! This is extremely helpful for me.
